# What is the action doing in this html page?

Tags: php, html, oauth-2.0

Can any body help me to analysis the following html to tell me what the form action is doing for the **logined_form**?

```
<form name="logined_form" action="login" method="post" style="display:none;" >
    <input type="hidden" name="logined" value="true" />

        <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="78a32e4ee9d4242134124" />                  
        <input type="hidden" name="display" value="web" />                              
</form>

<div class="login" id="noLoginedDiv">
    <form name="login_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return check_form();">
        <ul>
            <li class="fix"><input name="username" class="u" value="Email" type="text" onclick="username_onclick();" onblur="username_onblur();"/>
            </li>
            <li class="fix"><input name="password" class="p" type="password" />
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="fix"><button>Authorize</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var login_form = null;
    var logined_form = null;
    var xmlhttp = null;

    function init(){
        login_form = document.forms["login_form"];
        logined_form = document.forms["logined_form"];
    }

    function submitAutoLogin(){
        logined_form.submit();
    }

    var check_form = function(){
        if(login_form["username"].value == "Email"){
            login_form["username"].select();
            return false;
        }
        if(login_form["password"].value == ""){
            login_form["password"].select();
            return false;
        }
        xmlhttp = CreateHTTPObject();
        if (xmlhttp) {
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api.mywebsite.com/login.do", true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            var query = "_=_";
            query += "&loginname=" + encodeURIComponent(login_form["username"].value);
            query += "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(login_form["password"].value);
            query += "&act=ajaxLogin2Json";
            query += "&app=oauth2";
            query += "&callback=login_callback";
            xmlhttp.send(query);
        }

        return false;
    };

    var login_callback = function(result){
        var status = result["system"];
        if(status == 0){
            showMsg("Password wrong");
            return ;
        }else if(status < 0){
            showMsg("Failed to login");
            return ;
        }
        submitAutoLogin();
    };
</script>
```

After login successfully, the ***submitAutoLogin()*** function is called so that the logined_form is submit. But I don't understand what the action="login" means. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Action is used if you want to submit the form on particular page. in action we specify the name of the page i.e **submit.php ** so by default the page is submitted to  that page. if your using ajax then you dont need action attribute.

Comment: It is there however it is not needed at that place.

Comment: I want to know what does the action in this line <form name="logined_form" action="login" method="post" style="display:none;" > mean?

Answer (score 1):

**ACTION** property mentions what exact action to be taken on form-submission. This **ACTION** property holds the value of "SCRIPT PAGE" which further contains the logic to manipulate the data received from the form.

In the code you have posted above - **ACTION** is kept empty and on **onSubmit** event its calling the javascript function **check_form()**.

**check_form()** further makes an **AJAX** call to server-side script and manipulates the form values.

Comment: The **ACTION** is not empty in loggined_form. This is what I'm asking for. The check_form use **AJAX** to call server script, then it will call the logined_form submit so that the action of the loggined_form is called. But I don't understand what it is. (The action is 'login') Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: **ACTION** property in the `<form>` tag is empty. onsubmit event calls the javascript function which further hits the script **"https://api.mywebsite.com/login.do"**. For now you can say **login.do** is the action for the form. I hope its much clear now.

Comment: The flow is: check_form() -> Ajax -> login_callback -> submitAutoLogin() -> logined_form.submit() -> action 'login'. 

But I don't know what this action 'login' mean because there is no page called **login** and there is no script called **login** either.

Comment: Ok. **"https://api.mywebsite.com/login.do"** is a server side scripting which you will need to explore your self. Please locate this file on your server and see the logic in that.

Comment: There are two forms in my code. I'm not asking the one with the empty action. Instead I'm asking the other one.

Comment: In any case you will need to open the script located at `"https://api.mywebsite.com/login.do"`.

Comment: There are two forms in my code. One is with empty action which will call  "api.mywebsite.com/login.do" through ajax. The action for the other form (**logined_form**) is 'login' which apparently is not the same as the page **login.do**.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the action is the endpoint whereto the data is submitted. If your action is form.php the data will be posted to the file form.php.

When your catch the form with javascript in combination with AJAX the action isn't used in the most situations. Only in case if the action is fetch to post to by grabbing the action value to use is for some purposes.

Comment: If Javascript is disabled by the user, or if Javascript crashed for any reason, it might be good to keep an existing page in `action` attribute, so that the form would still work (even if it doesn't look as good as it would have with Javascript/AJAX).